# amount after ',' cannot be read

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a js code that calculate the total amount when being click by checkbox. The user can either choose to select all or select only certain amount that they want to calculate. The function if the user 'select all'is work fine but when they click only certain amount that they want to calculate, if the amount is have ','in it, it will only take the number before the ','for example if the amount is 20,230, it will total the amount as 20.00. it work real fine if the number is only 20230 without the ','. help me please.

```js
function checkedAll () {
 
   var row_counter =0; 
   $("input[id ^= 'check_'] ").each(function() {     
   row_counter++;    
   });//en
   var total=0;
   for(var i=1; i<=row_counter; i++) {
   //alert(i);
     if (document.getElementById("checkall").checked==true){
    document.getElementById('check_'+i).checked = true;
    var amaun = document.getElementById('amaun_'+i).value;
    //alert(amaun);
    total = parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(amaun);
     }
     else{
    document.getElementById('check_'+i).checked = false;
    var amaun = 0;
    total = parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(amaun);
     }
    
   }
   
   document.getElementById("jum_baucar").value=total.toFixed(2);
}

function calcTotal(){
 //alert("here");
  var row_counter =0; 
   $("input[id ^= 'check_'] ").each(function() {     
   row_counter++;    
   });//en
   var total=0;
   for(var i=1; i<=row_counter; i++) {
   //alert(i);
     if (document.getElementById('check_'+i).checked == true){
    var amaun = document.getElementById('amaun_'+i).value;
    //alert(amaun);
    total = parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(amaun);
     }
     else{    
    var amaun = 0;
    total = parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(amaun);
     }
    
   }
   
   document.getElementById("jum_baucar").value=total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Those are my js code.
what should I add into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `,` in a number that is applied with `parseFloat()` treats it as a decimal. For example `parseFloat('10,10') => 10`. One simple solution is simply removing the `,` from the string:

```
amaun = amaun.replace(',',''); // Replace a comma with nothing
```

Or for several commas using a regexp to act as a "`replaceAll()`":

```
amaun = amaun.replace(RegExp(',','g'),'');
```

Then you can apply `parseFloat(amaun)`:

```
total = parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(amaun);
```

Comment: where should i place it? i have no idea at all since i try so many ways but still can't get the solution.

Comment: @NurhidayahAbdullah Inbetween `var amaun = document.getElementById('amaun_'+i).value;` and `total = parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(amaun);` in both sections of your code.

Comment: i already try it but it is not work. The output of the amount didn't come out.

Comment: @NurhidayahAbdullah Then you are not accessing it correctly when doing  `getElementById`. This solution will work assuming you are correctly getting the value you stated `amaun` has. Could you provide a fiddle example of your code?

Comment: it is correct just those small problem that i mention occur. there is no other way to solve it?

Comment: @NurhidayahAbdullah My solution solves the exact question you have, and explains why it's happening. I'm confused why you can't use the method in my answer, why can't you use that as a solution?

Comment: i know the solution of yours is correct. i ask my friend too and she give me the same answer. it should be wrong somewhere with my code. i'm going to check on my code.

Comment: i get it now. i accidently add the code in my else clause too. once i delete it, its work fine for me now. thank you @Spencer Wieczorek